# Unable to get output when sending commands via ssh.net to aruba switch or virtual controller

Tags: c#, networking, ssh, ssh.net, aruba

I am attempting to remote into a virtual controller to run aruba commands into the console such as "show run" etc but no output is coming up for the commands. It appears I am able to successfully connect, and I am not seeing any errors, but nothing happens when running a command.

I have connected via putty to validate the commands, and also validate credentials. I have been able to do similar functionality via python, but am needing to be able to do this via C# for dependency reasons.

```
                var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
                methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(UserName, Password));
                var con = new ConnectionInfo(virtualController, 22, UserName, methods.ToArray());

                Console.WriteLine("Attempting Connection with Network...");
                var Client = new SshClient(con);
                Client.Connect();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully Connected.");

                var cmdRun = Client.RunCommand(showClients);
                var result = cmdRun.Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                cmdRun = Client.RunCommand(showRun);
                result = cmdRun.Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                Client.Disconnect();
```

The console outputs "Successfully Connected." and continues to execute all code, but never outputs anything on the line:

Console.WriteLine(result);

I would expect for the terminals output that I would see when running this command via putty.

Comment: Certain SSH implementations on network devices especially, do not properly support SSH Command Execution via the exec channel as used by `RunCommand` (Aruba and Cisco ASA are two of them). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484228/2557128) here on using `ShellStream` instead. I am actually using that code in a console shell for managing Aruba switches.

Comment: So I tried writing it as a default shell stream, and wrote a command into it, flushed the stream, and than tried to read the stream, but all it does is read me back what i wrote...how do you get back the response this way?

Answer (score 0):

I use `SSHClient` instead of `Client`. Using my class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484228/2557128), here's some sample code after calling `Client.Connect()`:

```
SSHStream = SSHClient.CreateExtShellStream("dumb", 120, 80, 0, 0, 65536);
if (SSHStream != null) {
    DoCommand("no page");
    Connected = true;
}

var result = DoCommand("show cdp neighbors | begin Port", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), "#");
```

Here is the helper method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoCommand(string c, TimeSpan? timeout = null, string prompt = "#") {
    return SSHStream.DoCommand(c, timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), prompt);
}
```

Comment: There's no `CreateExtShellStream` in SSH.NET

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry, that was part of the answer code I mentioned in my comment on your post. I added a link to my answer.